# How to pass className style to sub component in `material-ui`?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI uses `className` for stying. But how can I pass the style to sub react component?

Below is my style definition.

```
const styles = createStyles({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
        boxShadow: 'none',
        paddingTop: '25px',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      },
      subComponentStyle: {
         ...
      }
    });
```

And I use this like:

```
...
const NavigationBar = (props) => {
   const { classes } = props;
   return ( 
       <div className={classes.root}>
        // Add other code here
          <SubComponent ... > // how to pass `classes.subComponentStyle` style here
       </div>
   )
}
...
export default withStyles(styles)(NavigationBar);
```

If the `SubComponent` component is also exported with `withStyles`. How can I pass some styles to override its own styling?

My `SubComponent` is exported as:

```
const styles = createStyles({
   ...
});

const SubComponent = ({classes}) => {
...
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SubComponent);
```

as you can see, it has its own `classes`. I don't want to override its classes completely. Is there a way to merge the passed in classes with its internal classes?

Answer (score 4):

**// Edited to merged styles**

MUI will merge styles if you pass the classes as well as wrap the child withStyles. ie:

```
import { styles } from './NavStyles'

const NavigationBar = (props) => {
   const { classes } = props;
   return ( 
       <div className={classes.root}>
          <SubComponent classes={classes} >
       </div>
   )
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NavigationBar);
```

and in then also apply styles to the child component

```
import { styles } from './SubCompStyles'

const SubComponent = ({classes}) => {
 // classes object is a merge of both parent and child styles
 // ... component logic
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SubComponent)
```

Comment: My `SubComponent` also has its own `classes`. I don't want to override the SubComponent style completely. Is there a way to merge the passed in classes with the internal classes?

Comment: The classes should automatically get merged with the internal classes by `withStyles` when using the second approach in this answer (passing `classes` via SubComponent's `classes` property).

Comment: I just tried @RyanCogswell's solution - and can confirm they do merge.

Comment: how is this supposed to work when you're using typescript and the two types don't match up?

Comment: it will show **Warning: Material-UI: the key `xxx` provided to the classes property object is not implemented in SubComponent.** if NavigationBar && SubComponent classes object keys are not sync. According to [link](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7402#issuecomment-362254546), I would suggest using <SubComponent parentClasses={classes} > and not to merge classes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how you can do it with hook API:

**Sub component**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    color: 'white',
    padding: '0 30px',
    width: '12em',
    height: 43,
    borderRadius: 21.5,
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  ... your styles here. 
  },
}))

export default function AuthSecondaryButton(props) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  console.log('s', props.className)
  return (
    <Button
      {...props}
      className={clsx({
        [classes.root]: true,
        [props.className]: true,
      })}
    />
  )
}
```

**Parent component**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

 secondaryButton: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}))


export default function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles()
return(
  <AuthSecondaryButton
              onClick={onClickSecondaryButton}
              className={classes.secondaryButton}
            >
              Sign Up
            </AuthSecondaryButton>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak to @clever_usernames approach.
This uses `classnames` package instead of the `clsx` package, which we use in our project.

Replacing this...

```
   className={clsx({
        [classes.root]: true,
        [props.className]: true,
      })}
```

with this...

```
className={classNames(classes.root, props.className)}
```

---

### Full Example

**Sub component**

```
import classNames from 'classnames'

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderRadius: 3,
    color: 'white',
    padding: '0 30px',
    width: '12em',
    height: 43,
    borderRadius: 21.5,
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  ... your styles here. 
  },
}))

export default function AuthSecondaryButton(props) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  console.log('s', props.className)
  return (
    <Button
      {...props}
      className={classNames(classes.root, props.className)}
    />
  )
}
```

**Parent component**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({

 secondaryButton: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}))


export default function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles()
return(
  <AuthSecondaryButton
              onClick={onClickSecondaryButton}
              className={classes.secondaryButton}
            >
              Sign Up
            </AuthSecondaryButton>
)
```